# Extract .jar file with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, jar, extract

I need to extract a JAR file using NodeJS and I have no idea how, also I'm not sure if StackOverFlow is the right place for this so sorry if it's not.

Comment: Yes I've looked it up, I've been looking for several hours now. I can't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so jar files are just java archive files that can be unzipped with any commonly available operating system tool like `unzip` or `jar`, so a simple command like `jar xvf /path/to/file.jar` or `unzip /path/to/file.jar`  should extract any .jar file. But since you want to use nodeJS to do it, you can make use of the `exec` function present in the node js code module called `child_process`.

you can create a simple function which takes in the path to the jar file like

```js
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

extractJar(path) => {
  const command = `jar xvf ${path}`;
  exec(command, (err, stdout) => {
    if(err) console.log(err); return;
    console.log('success!');
  })
}
```

alternatively, you try by using libraries like [unzipper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unzipper), these do not depend upon your operating system tools as the exec command just executes the process on your shell, but these libraries use your node js IO operations for extracting.

Comment: Thanks for this! I actually already tried unzipper but with no luck, it gave me the following error: `Unhandled rejection Error: invalid signature: 0xa20200a`. If you know how to fix that then that'd be cool, but if not then do you know a way I can use your solution to unzip a file on windows?

Comment: yes it should work, try this command first `jar xvf /path/to/.jar` if this works the above snippet should

Comment: It works! Thanks. How can I specify a destination directory for the extracted files?

Comment: Also, several of them error with this: `Error: Command failed: jar xvf "C:\Users\redacted\OneDrive\Desktop\MC Plugin Finder\plugins-without-dependencies\goPaint.jar"
java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found`

Comment: Ah after doing some testing I think the ones not working have been compiled with gradle, how should I go about decompiling these ones?

Comment: so can you try using the unzip command in place of the jar utillity

Comment: `unzip` isn't a command